# How to push sqlLite database data to Firestore databas?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, sqlite, dart

In my app I used firestore database. Its working fine on online. But Now I want to use local storage as sqlLite. When my device is offline, data will save on sqlLite database and when the device is back to online it push the data to firestore database.
I used Flutter to develop the app. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase works as an offline database as well. When there is no Internet connection, all data changes are kept offline and then pushed to the cloud once it is possible.

If you insist on using a different database offline, I would recommend using `Hive`, since it also allows storing data in a document format.

Comment: I don't know, is friebase work frequently in offline? If its work frequently than its the best option i think.

Comment: Here is the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: got the solution. Thanks.